# NuGet Update-Database is not pulling new records in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs, nuget

Novice to VisualStudio and NuGet so I'm looking for some instruction.

I'm on a team project using TFS and using NuGet to get updates for the database of this project. 
One of my team members added in a property, that added a column to one of our databases, and then also added a new record to that database. Then he created a new migration for that instance.

I am trying to update this into the rest of our VisualStudio setups.
From my research so far, I ran the command `Update-Database` in the NuGet package manager. This updated the structure of the database and brought in the new column but failed to bring in the new record.

We have tried `Update-Database -force` and that came back with nothing.

I've tried searching for a solution but I'm having a hard time finding information on migrating data in the database.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about this easily for many future updates.

Comment: Can you please include the migration code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to SO!

> This updated the structure of the database and
>   brought in the new column but failed to bring in the new record.

When you create a migration, EF will automatically add the structural changes but it doesn't do the same for data. Which, if you think about it, makes sense as EF has no way of knowing what records have been added, amended or removed in your database and 9 times out of 10 we wouldn't want that data being in a migration script.

If you want to include records with your migration you have two options...

**1. Seed The Database**

This method will be called upon each migration

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApplication15.DatabaseContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(WebApplication15.DatabaseContext context)
    {
        //
        // Add records into the database
        //

    }
}
```

**2. Add Data to the Migration**

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        Sql("INSERT INTO People....");

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.People");
    }
}
```

> We have tried Update-Database -force and that came back with nothing.

The force flag just tells EF to migrate the database regardless of whether or not it might result in data loss (i.e dropping a table that is full of records!).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! We've decided its outside the scope of this current project and whats most important is the structure of the databases.